# Reopening question about becoming a good advisor?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness, closed-questions

I recently asked a [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/103485/18238) which recieved some attention. But was closed as off-topic (Shopping question).

Basically my question is about training or which steps I can take to become a good advisor. As a "good advisor" is not clearly defined I tried to provide some skills I thought he/she should have. But I might have then lean into a shopping question.

I would appreciate further guidance on how to rewrite the question to keep it open and address my point.

A user suggested to split the question in two. I think that questions would be:

- What skills should (ideally) a good advisor have?
  Which I think is a shopping question, and
- How to acquire the skills needed on to become a good advisor.

But before doing so I though better to discuss it here.

Comment: The votes are in favour of splitting the question?

Answer (score 1):

The advice to split a question is always good advice, but in this case the split questions still do not work well. Both the questions *What skills should (ideally) a good advisor have* and *How to acquire the skills needed on to become a good advisor* seem like they lead to lots of answers with one, or more, skills/ways of obtaining them and each answer will be equally valid. This is often what we refer to as a shopping question. I am not sure the topic works for the SE model.

Comment: I agree, but then how I split the question in new meaningful questions?

Comment: There are some questions for which there does not exist a suitable way of asking on Stack Exchange. *How do I become really good at [broad role]?* is one of them. *What [property] does a [broad type of object] need?* is another.

Comment: These aren't even shopping questions though, they're just straight-up TB.